# Action/Martial Arts anime with a character fighting with feathers

Tags: fuuma-no-kojirou

I believe the anime was in the 90's. Artwork looked similar to YuYu Hakusho. Action/Martial Arts anime. One thing that I remembered most about the opening theme was that there was a part where the wind blew past him and he disappered into the with like a ninja.

The main character is a funny guys who plays around too much. He is a great fighter, moves like the wind, and in the beginning of the anime he protects this girls from a group of thugs. He also had a friend who helped him and the girl escape from a bad guy.

His friend uses feathers as weapons. From what I can remember he had red, blue, and black feathers that he used. Some feathers that he threw could turn around like boomerangs. Eventually as the main character escapes with the girl (I think), his friend fights till then end and gets killed.

The killer has this ability where he can copy other people's face by pressing the people he kill face's into the ground, pours some liquid into the ground, puts his face into the mold he created with the dead person's face and he can copy their face.

After killing the main character's friend he goes after the main character with a fake face posing as the main character's friend. That's all that I can remember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like [**Fūma no Kojirō**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C5%ABma_no_Kojir%C5%8D)

> Hakuō Academy used to be a prestigious high school, and famous for martial arts. However, because its rival school Seishikan has been cowardly luring its superior students, Hakuō was going to decline. In order to recover from the situation, the acting principal of Hakuō; Himeko Hōjō, sends Ranko Yagyū to the Fūma village in search of the famous Fūma ninja clan for assistance. The leader of the Fūma sent Kojirō to Hakuō, there he faces the notorious Yasha clan who fights for Seishikan led by Musashi Asuka. Kojirō's comrades arrive, resuming an all-out ninja war that began five centuries ago.

There are two twins **Kou** and **Shoryu**, who fought with feathers (white, blue, red and black).

In episode 3, Kou fought with two guys, **Byakko** and **Shien**. After defeating Byakko, before Kou could deal the final blow to Byakko, he was interrupted and killed by Shien. However, before he died, he managed to kill Shien with a black feather. Byakko, who survived the fight, copied Kou's face by pressing his face to the ground, pouring a liquid in the hole and then immersing his own face into it. [This](http://youtu.be/GARn0w6O8UM?t=15m30s) is the scene where Kou fought with the feathers, and [this](http://youtu.be/GARn0w6O8UM?t=23m52s) is the moment when Byakko used his "copy ability".

There are 4 kind of feathers:

- **white feathers** are used to attack (they randomly attack the enemy as flying blades) and help to identify the position of the enemy (forming something like a web around the user).
- **blue feathers** are thrown like knives.
- **red feathers** come back as boomerangs stabbing the enemy in the back.
- **black feathers** hide themselves in the shadow of other feathers.

Later in the story, Shoryu would see through Byakko's disguise and fight with him to avenge his brother.

Below are pictures of Byakko and Kou.

[image: Byakko]
[image: Kou]